# What are the hotkeys to find the next and previous occurrence of a search term in man and info?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, manpage, info

Let's say you wanted to search the documentation for mplayer:

```
# man mplayer
```

To search for "length" you would type "/length" while in man and press enter.  To go to the next occurrence of "length" you would type "n".  What is the hotkey to get to the previous occurrence of "n"?

And what are the hotkeys to get to the next and previous occurrences of a search term in info?

```
# info mplayer
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the `man` command, as you say, use `/YOUR_SEARCH` to find the first occurance of YOUR_SEARCH and then `n` to get to the next one.  Use `N` to move to the previous occurrence.

For the `info` command, type `s` to search, then enter your search term or regex.  It will bring you to the first occurrence.  To move to the next match, type `}`, to move to the previous occurrence type `{`.